# sql query for displaying a new column based on condition on existing columns

Tags: sql

I am new to sql. I have a problem where I have to display an additional column based on some condition on existing columns.
Existing table:

```
--------------------
 pid | ppid | path |
--------------------
111  | 120  | xyz  |
120  | 230  | abc  |
```

Where 'pid' -> processid , 'ppid' -> parent process id , 'path' -> path of process pid

I want to write a SQL query to display all these rows along with a new column 'ppath' which denotes the path of parent process. And this info can be retrieved from existing table itself.
But I am not sure how to do this.
Eg output:

```
--------------------------
 pid | ppid | path | ppath|
--------------------------
111  | 120  | xyz  | abc  |
120  | 230  | abc  |      |
```

Any suggestions would be helpful.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can (left) join the table to itself. Let's say your table is called `process`:

```
SELECT
   process.pid, 
   process.ppid, 
   process.path, 
   parent_process.path as ppath
FROM process
LEFT JOIN process as parent_process
ON process.ppid = parent_process.pid
```

Answer (score 1):

Its coding might be different based on the backend used but you didn't tag what you are using. For a general SQL:

```
select t1.*, t2.path as ppath
from myTable t1
left join myTable t2 on t1.ppid = t2.pid;
```